# Wordpress Command Question

Tags: customization

Ok would like to learn how to run commands through WP rather than SQL commands

So I have created a text file named delete-non-authors.php to delete authors with no posts

Do I need to add this to a folder before uploading?

What are the permissions to execute this plugin?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to add this to a folder before uploading?

If the plugin only consists of this single file, then no, a folder is not required(but you can use a folder if you prefer).

> What are the permissions to execute this plugin?

If you're talking about folder and file permissions, these are usually 755 for directories and 644 for files.

If that's not what you mean, it's down to your plugin to determine the capabilities required to run/view it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: If the question has been sufficiently answered, please consider marking the answer as correct. :)